# What's the formal way to say "get to know"?

Tags: formality, letter-writing, greetings

For example in the sentence "Hereby I express my pleasure ... you on behalf of ABC Company."

Comment: Define "formal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Make someone's acquaintance](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/make-someone-s-acquaintance):

> - (formal)  to ​meet someone:
>     I’m very ​pleased to make ​your ​acquaintance.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

- It is a pleasure  to make your acquaintance on behalf of...